# How to check if CCAction is running - cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm using Cocos2d to write game for iPhone.
Here's the problem.

I have CCSprite and CCAction which is run on it.

```
CCSprite texture;
CCAction anim_action;
```

"Anim_action" is a CCRepeatForever action.
Now I want to check if this animation is running.

First I though I can use [isDone] function, but I think it doesn't work on CCRepatForever actions (I'm not sure - this opion is based on my tests)

So how to check if this animation is already running on my "texture"?

Maybe there is a way to get name of action which is running on texture at the moment?
It may be also useful!

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to check if a specific action runs on your texture. Use:

```
CCAction *action = [texture getActionByTag:kAsignedActionTag];
```

where *kAsignedActionTag* is the tag assigned to the your animation.

```
anim_action.tag = kAsignedActionTag;
```

If your action is still running the *getActionByTag* method will not return nil.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to directly tell if a CCRepeatForever action has completed since the isDone would make no sense, but there are some techniques you can use to essentially provide a callback to indicate if something is still running:

1. Override the step: method and call out to something that checks the interval - when it exceeds a threshold you can assume completion...kinda'
2. Wrap the inner action of the CCRepeatForever with a CCSequence.  The first action of the sequence would be your repeated action and the second would be a CCCalFunc, again indicating that the action is still running
3. Subclass the CCRepeatForever and override the dealloc so you can fire a callback when the action is killed and released

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [isDone] while appling an effect

```
- (void)shakeThatThingOn: (BOOL)on { //you can return BOOL and get if the animation is working or not
 if (on == YES){
  id shaky2 = [CCShaky3D actionWithRange:3 shakeZ:NO grid:ccg(15,10) duration:5];
  if (![shaky2 isDone])
   [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:shaky2,[CCStopGrid action],nil]];

 }
 else {//this else is being called when you turn off animation (it's just 0.2s continuation after turning off - for better visual effect.

  [self stopAllActions];
  id shaky2 = [CCShaky3D actionWithRange:3 shakeZ:NO grid:ccg(15,10) duration:0.2];
  [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:shaky2,[CCStopGrid action],nil]];
 }}
```

and control it by simple BOOL if it's on or off.
I don't know if it's what you mean, but hope it'll help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many actions will be running on the sprite, or if the animation is the only action, then you can infer that the animation is running by checking the sprite's total number of running actions.

```
if ([texture numberOfRunningActions] > 0) //animation is running
```

or

```
if ([texture numberOfRunningActions] > someNumber) //if you had other actions running
```